# ¿Por qué disminuye la frecuencia de ejecución del evento touchmove usando dos dedos o más?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de manejar la traslación y la escala de un canvas a través de gestos, por ahora solo he podido implementar la traslación por lo siguiente: me he dado cuenta de que **cuando uso dos dedos o más**, la **frecuencia de disparo del evento** (en este caso **touchmove**) **disminuye considerablemente**, pero solo ocurre si la **distancia entre las posiciones de los toques varía**, es decir, si yo pongo dos dedos en la pantalla y ambos los **traslado igual** (manteniendo la **misma distancia entre los dedos**) el evento se dispara correctamente, pero en cambio si **a la vez que traslado los dedos los junto y los alejo** es cuando se produce esa **variación en la frecuencia de disparo del evento**, el código es el siguiente:

```
(function( d ) {

   var evts = {
     start: 'touchstart',
     move: 'touchmove',
     end: 'touchend'
   };

   var old = {
     tchs: [],
     trans: {
       x: 0,
       y: 0
     }
   };

   var tchs = [];

   function start( e ) {

     tchs = [];
     old.tchs = e.touches;

     old.trans.x = DRAWER.trans.x;
     old.trans.y = DRAWER.trans.y;

   }

   var tOld; //esto lo estoy usando para comprobar
   //el tiempo que tarda en dispararse cada evento "touchmove"

   function move( e ) {
     let tNow = Date.now();
     console.log( tNow - tOld );
     tchs = e.touches;
     tOld = tNow;
   }


   function renderTchs() { //gestionar los toques

     if (tchs.length == 1) {
       let tx = old.trans.x + (tchs[0].clientX - old.tchs[0].clientX);
       let ty = old.trans.y + (tchs[0].clientY - old.tchs[0].clientY);

       DRAWER.setTrans( tx, ty );
     }


     //aquí trabajaría también la escala, 
     //pero al usar dos dedos me ocurre el retardo 
     //y antes de implementarlo quiero saber por qué ocurre

     window.requestAnimationFrame( renderTchs );

   }

   renderTchs();

   d.body.addEventListener(evts.start,( e ) => {
     tOld = Date.now();
     start( e );
   },false);
   d.body.addEventListener(evts.move,move,false);
   //d.body.addEventListener(evts.end,end,false);

   d.body.addEventListener('touchmove',( e ) => {
     e.preventDefault();
   });

 })( document );
```

[image: Event delay]

Como se muestra en la consola el evento se empieza a disparar **cada 200 ms** más o menos, eso es excesivo y provoca que **el supuesto cambio de escala (aún sin implementar) se vaya a producir a trompicones**.

En el `<head>` de la página tengo establecido esto:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Y de CSS estas líneas:

```
html, body {
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  overflow: hidden; /* Evitar recargar la página deslizando hacia abajo en Android Chrome */
}
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Espero haberme expresado con la suficiente claridad, si alguien pudiera aclararme lo que está ocurriendo se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indagando un poco me puse a buscar en los flags de Chrome con la palabra "touch" y encontré esto:

[image]

Pues cambiando el valor a **Enabled** el evento ya se disparaba correctamente, pero nada más ver esto me di cuenta de que ni mucho menos era necesario cambiar ningún flag de Chrome y **es tan sencillo como hacer lo siguiente**:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove',( e ) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //=> prevenimos las acciones por defecto
    //...el evento ya no sufre retardos!!!
},{passive: false}); //=> deshabilitamos la pasividad
```

La explicación de los **Oyentes de Eventos Pasivos** la encontré **[aquí](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md)**, y entendí más o menos que el propio **navegador estaba provocando esos bloqueos/retardos a propósito al estar activado el modo pasivo**.

¡Espero que sirva de ayuda!

Comment: Simplemente increíble, muchas gracias por tu aporte, no sé cómo todavía nadie te ha dado un voto positivo. Aquí tienes el mío. ¿Por casualidad tienes tu proyecto en un repo público? Estaría interesado en ver el progreso

Comment: @RobertoPintosLópez Muchas gracias Roberto por tu valoración! Es un proyecto particular que únicamente lo tengo alojado en un servidor local de casa, simplemente estoy trasteando con las mates para hacer movimientos sinusoidales. Un saludo!